# Pyspark : How to find and convert top 5 row values to 1 and rest all to 0?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe and i need to find the maximum 5 values in each row, convert only those values to 1 and rest all to 0 while maintaining the dataframe structure, i.e. the column names should remain the same

I tried using toLocalIterator and then converting each row to a list, then converting top 5 to values 1.
But it gives me a java.lang.outOfMemoryError when i run the code on large dataset.
While looking at the logs i found that a task of very large size(around 25000KB) is submitted while the max recommended size is 100KB

Is there a better way to find and convert top 5 values to a certain value(1 in this case) and rest all to 0, which would utilize less memory

EDIT 1:

For example if i have this 10 columns and 5 rows as the input

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|  10|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|0.74| 0.9|0.52|0.85|0.18|0.23| 0.3| 0.0| 0.1|0.07|
|0.11|0.57|0.81|0.81|0.45|0.48|0.86|0.38|0.41|0.45|
|0.03|0.84|0.17|0.96|0.09|0.73|0.25|0.05|0.57|0.66|
| 0.8|0.94|0.06|0.44| 0.2|0.89| 0.9| 1.0|0.48|0.14|
|0.73|0.86|0.68| 1.0|0.78|0.17|0.11|0.19|0.18|0.83|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

this is what i want as the output

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

as you can see i want to find the top(max) 5 values in each row convert them to 1 and the rest of the values to 0, while maintaining the structure i.e. rows and columns

this is what i am using (which gives me outOfMemoryError)

```
for row in prob_df.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    rowPredDict = {}
    for cat in categories:
        rowPredDict[cat]= row[cat]
        sorted_row = sorted(rowPredDict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1],reverse=True)
    #print(rowPredDict)
    rowPredDict = rowPredDict.fromkeys(rowPredDict,0)
    rowPredDict[sorted_row[0:5][0][0]] = 1
    rowPredDict[sorted_row[0:5][1][0]] = 1
    rowPredDict[sorted_row[0:5][2][0]] = 1
    rowPredDict[sorted_row[0:5][3][0]] = 1
    rowPredDict[sorted_row[0:5][4][0]] = 1
    #print(count,sorted_row[0:2][0][0],",",sorted_row[0:2][1][0])
    rowPredList.append(rowPredDict)
    #count=count+1
```

Comment: you need to explain your case with some sample data along with your expected output.

Comment: try provinding an example of what u want..

Comment: I have edited the question with an example and the code which i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough volume for performance testing but could you try below approach using spark `functions array` apis

**1. Prepare Dataset:**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

l1 = [(0.74,0.9,0.52,0.85,0.18,0.23,0.3,0.0,0.1,0.07),
    (0.11,0.57,0.81,0.81,0.45,0.48,0.86,0.38,0.41,0.45),
    (0.03,0.84,0.17,0.96,0.09,0.73,0.25,0.05,0.57,0.66),
    (0.8,0.94,0.06,0.44,0.2,0.89,0.9,1.0,0.48,0.14),
    (0.73,0.86,0.68,1.0,0.78,0.17,0.11,0.19,0.18,0.83)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6','col_7','col_8','col_9','col_10')
df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 0.74|  0.9| 0.52| 0.85| 0.18| 0.23|  0.3|  0.0|  0.1|  0.07|
| 0.11| 0.57| 0.81| 0.81| 0.45| 0.48| 0.86| 0.38| 0.41|  0.45|
| 0.03| 0.84| 0.17| 0.96| 0.09| 0.73| 0.25| 0.05| 0.57|  0.66|
|  0.8| 0.94| 0.06| 0.44|  0.2| 0.89|  0.9|  1.0| 0.48|  0.14|
| 0.73| 0.86| 0.68|  1.0| 0.78| 0.17| 0.11| 0.19| 0.18|  0.83|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

**2. Get top 5 for each row**

Following below steps on `df`

- Create array and Sort the elements
- Get first 5 elements into new column called `all`

UDF to get Max 5 elements from sorted:

***Note :***  **spark >= 2.4.0** have [`slice`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.slice) function which can do similar task. I am using 2.2 in currently so creating **UDF** but if you have 2.4 or higher version then you can give a try with `slice`

```
def get_n_elements_(arr, n):
                return arr[:n]

get_n_elements = f.udf(get_n_elements_, t.ArrayType(t.DoubleType()))

df_all = df.withColumn('all', get_n_elements(f.sort_array(f.array(df.columns), False),f.lit(5)))

df_all.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------------------------------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|all                           |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------------------------------+
|0.74 |0.9  |0.52 |0.85 |0.18 |0.23 |0.3  |0.0  |0.1  |0.07  |[0.9, 0.85, 0.74, 0.52, 0.3]  |
|0.11 |0.57 |0.81 |0.81 |0.45 |0.48 |0.86 |0.38 |0.41 |0.45  |[0.86, 0.81, 0.81, 0.57, 0.48]|
|0.03 |0.84 |0.17 |0.96 |0.09 |0.73 |0.25 |0.05 |0.57 |0.66  |[0.96, 0.84, 0.73, 0.66, 0.57]|
|0.8  |0.94 |0.06 |0.44 |0.2  |0.89 |0.9  |1.0  |0.48 |0.14  |[1.0, 0.94, 0.9, 0.89, 0.8]   |
|0.73 |0.86 |0.68 |1.0  |0.78 |0.17 |0.11 |0.19 |0.18 |0.83  |[1.0, 0.86, 0.83, 0.78, 0.73] |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------------------------------+
```

**3. Create dynamic sql and execute with `selectExpr`**

```
sql_stmt = ''' case when array_contains(all, {0}) then 1 else 0 end AS `{0}` '''
df_all.selectExpr(*[sql_stmt.format(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|    1|    1|    1|    1|    0|    0|    1|    0|    0|     0|
|    0|    1|    1|    1|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|     0|
|    0|    1|    0|    1|    0|    1|    0|    0|    1|     1|
|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|    1|    1|    1|    0|     0|
|    1|    1|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|     1|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Your code works on the huge dataset that i wanted to work on, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily like this.

For example we want to do that task for value column, so first sort the value column take the 5th value and change the values using a when condition.

```
df2 = sc.parallelize([("fo", 100,20),("rogerg", 110,56),("franre", 1080,297),("f11", 10100,217),("franci", 10,227),("fran", 1002,5),("fran231cis", 10007,271),("franc3is", 1030,2)]).toDF(["name", "salary","value"])
df2 = df2.orderBy("value",ascending=False)

+----------+------+-----+
|      name|salary|value|
+----------+------+-----+
|    franre|  1080|  297|
|fran231cis| 10007|  271|
|    franci|    10|  227|
|       f11| 10100|  217|
|    rogerg|   110|   56|
|        fo|   100|   20|
|      fran|  1002|    5|
|  franc3is|  1030|    2|
+----------+------+-----+

maxx = df2.take(5)[4]["value"]
dff = df2.select(when(df2['value'] >= maxx, 1).otherwise(0).alias("value"),"name", "salary")

+---+----------+------+
|value|      name|salary|
+---+----------+------+
|  1|    franre|  1080|
|  1|fran231cis| 10007|
|  1|    franci|    10|
|  1|       f11| 10100|
|  1|    rogerg|   110|
|  0|        fo|   100|
|  0|      fran|  1002|
|  0|  franc3is|  1030|
+---+----------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think you misunderstood the question, i want to find the max 5 values for each row across all the columns in the dataframe. Also i dont want to change the ordering of the rows